# Hive Timestamp Differences in Milliseconds

Tags: hive, timestamp

A previous solution regarding obtaining an answer in milliseconds for differences between two timestamps does not work in Hive 1.0 on Amazon EMR.  Hive returns a blank column when casting a timestamp as double in my testing today.  No errors are thrown when doing the CAST.  Being able to calculate a time difference in fractions of a second between two columns of type "timestamp" are critical to our analysis.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to convert into unix_timestamp using unix_timestamp(timestamp) but I think you will still be losing milliseconds.

```
select (unix_timestamp(DATE1)-unix_timestamp(DATE2)) TIMEDIFF from TABLE;
```