# How to find time difference between two timestamps in seconds and milliseconds in hive and impala

Tags: hive, impala, cloudera-cdp

Need a help in finding time difference between two timestamps in seconds and milliseconds in hive and impala. We are using CDP cluster. Two columns are in string datatype with value in the format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

| t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-26T04:01:49.010 | 2023-01-26T04:01:47.863 |
| 2023-01-26T04:01:48.999 | 2023-01-25T04:01:47.001 |

I tried "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329652/hive-timestamp-differences-in-milliseconds" but in this milliseconds are ignored or missed so it is not giving accurate results. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To extract Unix timestamps, you can use the `unix_timestamp` and `FROM_UNIXTIME` functions. You need to ensure the format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

```
SELECT
  t1,
  t2,
  CAST(t1 AS TIMESTAMP) AS timestamp1,
  CAST(t2 AS TIMESTAMP) AS timestamp2,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS') AS time_diff_milliseconds
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We are using Apache Hive Version 3.1.3000.7.1.8.41-1. I didn't find TIMESTAMPDIFF function

Comment: Also in Impala  actual time difference in millisecond is just 147 millseconds .The query gives difference output which may not be correct
SELECT    
    CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:48.010' AS TIMESTAMP) AS T1,
    CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:47.863' AS TIMESTAMP) AS T2,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:48.010' AS TIMESTAMP)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:47.863' AS TIMESTAMP)) AS time_diff_seconds,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:48.010' AS TIMESTAMP)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST('2023-01-26T04:01:47.863' AS TIMESTAMP))) * 1000 AS time_diff_milliseconds

Comment: SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-26T04:01:48.010', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS') AS formatted_t1   this query also gives null in HIVE and IMPALA. Please help me on this

Comment: The `CAST` and `FROM_UNIXTIME` functions are available in both Hive and Impala where you need to convert it to `'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS'`